# PHP detect a special character

Tags: php, character

I want to do a function in php, that detects a character, and does an action.
Basically what CSV can do.

My Database Looks like this

`ID (INT) Auto_Increment

 LINK (INT)

 ADRESS (VARCHAR, 65)

 DATE (TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

The Value in Adress should be like   `Name;Street;Nr;Zip;City;`

And on the PHP Page it should do `Name </ br> Street &nspb Nr. </ br> Zip &nspb City`

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure you know how to program? Transforming strings into other strings is one of the most basic exercises you can do. Do you have a half-working solution for us?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Check this build in php function [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

query the value in Address, then explode it to an array, and next, output the formated string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your results are stored in an array called `$results`, you can do the following:

```
foreach ($row in $results)
{
      foreach ($address in explode(';', $row['address']))
      {
            echo "$address[0] </ br> $address[1] &nspb $address[2] </ br> $address[3] &nspb $address[4]";
      }
}
```